# Not generating the Activity and layout files while creating project

Tags: android, adt

I am using eclipse kepler version and latest ADT plugin. But when i tried to create an android project it is not creating the blank activity and layout file. I could see the same question asked many times. In all those links the answer is given like Help->install new software-> https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/.But when i tried this it is displaying like everything is already installed. So i need a proper solution.I am stuck with it. Please do help me.

Comment: can you please elaborate more what problems exactly... any screen shots might be helpful ?

Comment: i am creating android app with blank activity.when i tap on finish button app is created but the window for creating app is not disappearing. And the src and layout folders in the created project are empty.

Comment: ok then this might be the problem with ADT. There is a bug that create these problems and they are frustrated. did you tried using empty activity instead ?
or you can try using the different version of eclipse like juno or indigo ?

Comment: try this link 
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72591

Comment: i have tried the same with indigo but same issue. And tried empty activity.then files are created but getting R cannot be resolved error :(

Comment: ok try creating your project by changing the target SDK to Android 'JellyBean' or 'KitKat' rather than 'API21'.

Comment: Maybe yout should try Android studio. It's very easy to use and it just release the 1.0 version

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem as you

and I found this

> ADT 23.0.4 (October 2014)
>
> Dependencies:
> Java 7 or higher is required if you are targeting the L Developer Preview.
> Java 1.6 or higher is required if you are targeting other releases.
> Eclipse Indigo (Version 3.7.2) or higher is required.
> **This version of ADT is designed for use with SDK Tools r23.0.2**. If you haven't already installed SDK Tools r23.0.2 into your SDK, use the Android SDK Manager to do so.

so...I delete the newest version of SDK Tools 24.0.1

download and install older version SDK Tools r23.0.2

http://dl.google.com/android/installer_r23.0.2-windows.exe

it works for me....

Comment: SDK tools 23.0.5 also works
and I found quicker to fixed the problem
download this
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r23.0.5-windows.zip
and just replace tool folder