# nothing in the src and layout folder

Tags: android, eclipse

First,the recent version of  adt is the lastest,and the sdk is level 21,after i create a new android project in eclipse in mac,there is nothing in the src and layout folders.So,I tried to create a new android activity in 
src folder,but the eclipse show a error that the refactoring does not change any source code.I have used most of the methods to solve my problem but failed.
It's my first time to use stack overflow...my english is not good.forgive me.if you can solve my problem,I will be very appreciate it.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[Not generating the Activity and layout files while creating project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27373309/not-generating-the-activity-and-layout-files-while-creating-project/27428516#27428516)

download this 
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r23.0.5-windows.zip 
and replace tool folder in android-sdk folder

Comment: sorry..can you give me another link in mac

Comment: on mac OS?
this link is not available?